# Button title set only for the second tab

Tags: swift

In my project there is a Segue Show(e.g. Push). After clicking the mainButton, TabBarController is presented. When I choose the second tab, the method `setButtonsTitle` is called and when I swipe the TabBarController down, I can see "item 2" instead of the "Button" title (default title). But when I click the first tab afterwards and swipe the TabBarController down, it remains "Button". My first thought was that the method does not get called, but this is not true (checked in debugger). Also, `print(title)` shows "Item 1".

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }  

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destination = segue.destination as! TabBarController
        destination.selectionDelegate = self
    }

}

extension ViewController : ButtonThings {
    func setButtonsTitle(title: String){
        mainButton.titleLabel?.text = title
        print(title)
    }
}
```

And the TabBarController:

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    weak var selectionDelegate: ButtonThings?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    //MARK: UITabBarController
    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        selectionDelegate?.setButtonsTitle(title: item.title ?? "no title")
    }

}

protocol ButtonThings : class {
    func setButtonsTitle(title: String)
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the notification center instead of delegate.

Comment: Yeah, there are different approaches to do this problem but I want to know what is wrong with the current implementation

Comment: Use mainButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)  instead of mainButton.titleLabel?.text = title. Your problem is this.

Comment: Just FYI: In your implementation of `override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {` you are breaking the tab bar controller. In part this is merely a failure to call `super`. But it is also unnecessary to do this override, as a tab bar controller already has a delegate that does what you need; subclassing UITabBarController is nearly always wrong, and so here.

Comment: @Kasım Özdemir thank you, this is working. But why did exactly the same method work when choosing item 2 ?

Comment: Apple says that you should use it this way if you want change button title. [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624018-settitle) . 
The title is actually changing, but then the old title is back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce that issue that you had mentioned. I then set the button type to custom and the button title started showing correctly.

[image: Button type - custom]

Hope this helps.

Comment: it is working (and Kasım Özdemir idea also), thanks !  but why does the button type affect the title setting ?

Comment: If the button type is custom, you can use titleLabel?.text. If the button type is system, you can use setTitle(title, for: .normal).